# How to insert JPEG into a SQL Server 2000 database field of image type using Transact SQL

Tags: t-sql, image, sql-server-2000, insert-update

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a .JPG file into a SQL Server 2000 database field of type image using Transact SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use OPENROWSET:

```
INSERT MyTable (ImageColumnName) 
SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\myjpeg.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X
```

**EDITED** Whoops, you're using 2000--the previous solution is not supported. You have to use WRITETEXT:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
    ImageColumnName IMAGE NULL
)
GO

-- must insert a dummy value into the image column for TEXTPTR 
-- to work in next bit
DECLARE @RowId INT
INSERT MyTable (ImageColumnName) VALUES (0xFFFFFFFF)
SELECT @RowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- get a pointer value to the row+column you want to 
-- write the image to
DECLARE @Pointer_Value varbinary(16)
SELECT @Pointer_Value = TEXTPTR(ImageColumnName)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Id = @RowId

-- write the image to the row+column pointer
WRITETEXT MyTable.ImageColumnName @Pointer_Value 'c:\myjpeg.jpg'
```

Comment: that's what i tried doing but i think it's sql server 2005 syntax, doesn't seem to work in 2000

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called textcopy.exe
You can find it under MSSQL\Binn or get it with SQL Server 2000 SP4

Alexander Chigrik wrote a nice stored procedure for usinig it with SQL query:

http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/KnowHow/Textcopy.htm

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure found in this tutorial worked for me:

[Brief tutorial on text, ntext, and image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175795%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)