# What is the easiest way to update an image field with the content of a file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a table in MS Sql server with an image field and a file.
What is the easiest way to create a T-Sql script that updates the field with the content of the file?

Comment: have a look at this SO-Article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214462/how-to-insert-jpeg-into-a-sql-server-2000-database-field-of-image-type-using-tran

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET BlobColumn = 
    (SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK  N'C:\YourFile.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: Just remember that if you're connecting to a remote database server, the path is relative to the server that the DB is on, not your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Drop table employees:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    myid int,
    myname varchar(50) not null,
    mypic varbinary(max) not null
)

INSERT INTO Employees (myid, myname, mypic) 
SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\delete\a.bmp', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture

UPDATE Employees SET [mypic] =
(
    SELECT MyImage.*
    from Openrowset(Bulk 'C:\Delete\B.bmp', Single_Blob) MyImage)
    where myid = 10
```

After column i.e. `MayImage` there should be `.*` otherwise, it will not work.