# How can I insert an array of bytes as text in the SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I use a text file with a correct sql insert-statement for bulk loading in my test project. I apply this statement to an empty table to load data. But I faced with the problem of writing an array of bytes.

How can I write the correct insert-statement that I used to pass an array of bytes? Will understand SQL Server 2008 an array of bytes as hex-string?

### Added

I need some string that I can apply to SQL Server to insert an array of bytes.
Something like that:

```
INSERT INTO T(SomeBlobColumn) VALUES (0x666F6F)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO T(SomeBlobColumn) VALUES (CAST('666F6F' AS BINARY))
```

Comment: You can use `INSERT INTO T(SomeBlobColumn) VALUES (0x666F6F)` if that's what you are asking?

Comment: @MartinSmith, does it mean 0x... is correct writting of an array of bytes?

Comment: That is how you represent a binary literal in a TSQL statement. But I'm not sure if that's what you want to do? You can also import the binary data in from a file in TSQL using [`OPENROWSET`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4376617/73226) or use the bcp utility or application code...

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach (in c#):

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableName(BinaryColumn) VALUES (@InputParameter)", sqlConnection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@InputParameter", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = byteArray;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I assume you are posting some c# code, but I'm not sure how you know the OP is trying to use that.

Comment: +1 for the approach. And since the OP is using NHibernate, as it had posted questions about it, I don't think it's a problem to write a small utility program.