# Unexpected character. (near "\"

Tags: mysql, sql, image, bulk

so I'm updating my tables within phpmyadmin. The data is in it, a column was successfully created. When I attempted to add images with the code below, I got this error

> Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 78)
>   Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 84)
>   Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 91)
>   Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 98)
>   Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 166)

Code:

```
UPDATE leleshwa SET BlobColumn = (SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\xampp\htdocs\images\Vitabiotics Wellwoman Drink.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img) WHERE ID = 1
```

**UPDATE**

When I switch the direction of the slash for the path (The N before the path seems to make no difference with or without),

`UPDATE leleshwa SET BlobColumn = (SELECT  BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:/xampp/htdocs/images/Vitabiotics Wellwoman Drink.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img) WHERE`ID`= 1`

the above errors disappear, but I get the following confusing error

> Ending quote ' was expected. (near "" at position 174)

What confuses me more is that the error points to the code by **img**, but position 174 is at the end of the query.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I am working through phpmyadmin. That's where I am hosting the database. It has all the necessary data, it just needs the images updated to each column. If I can get one right, I've got them all.

Comment: So... SQLite? mySQL? Which one?

Comment: I am using a PDO connection.

Comment: You need to figure out what is the flavor of the DB you are using. PDO connection is not a database. When you establish connection, what is the first word you use? Like `new PDO('mysql:...` or `new PDO('sqlite:...`?

Comment: My bad. I am super foggy from too much screentime. Mysql.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330314/bulk-insert-in-mysql)? Looks like you got syntax wrong. And I also don't think you can read jpg file just like a text file, but I haven't worked with mySQL enough to be sure

Comment: I actually got my syntax from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376087/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-update-an-image-field-with-the-content-of-a-file).

Comment: Right, that's not gonna work for you because the syntax is for SQL Server, not mySQL

Comment: This is just the SQL though. The mysql connection was for the building of the front end form. I didn't know that they would be connected even when independently. I'll do some digging and see if there's a different syntax when using mySQL instead of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

So for my solution, I changed the column type to varcar(100) (well, deleted the column and then created a new one) and then did the simple update with the filename. No path. Works like a charm.

I sincerely appreciate all the swift help.