# Store image in Data base after add many rows into the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a table in sql server database that contain image field like below 
[image: Table design]

and I already added some data into that table 
[image: table data]

now the problem is I need to add for each row of it image 
how I can do that in sql server

also I'll use that data into ASP.net project ( C# ) 
how can I retrieve that data into it

any help ???

Comment: See this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214462/how-to-insert-jpeg-into-a-sql-server-2000-database-field-of-image-type-using-tran

Comment: store the image data as varbinary(max).

Comment: You are using two deprecated datatypes here. Both the image and text datatypes are deprecated. You should be using varbinary(max) and varchar(max) respectively. You might also consider that 50 characters is woefully inadequate to store email addresses or website urls. It also seems you could do some normalization here too.

Comment: Please learn the difference between MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your image data type as VarBinary. Image data type is deprecated in sql server.

Once you have changed your data type for image to varbinary then you can take your image and convert to byte array and insert into the table.

Comment: can you share the code how to change the image to byte array and then insert it ?

Comment: How are you suppose to receive the image? through upload?