# Insert image into SQL Server 2000 table

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2000, firedac, fastreport

How can I insert image into SQL Server 2000 table and view that image
using TDBImage control or print it with Fast-Report in delphi?
The below solution working only with SQL Server 2005+

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\TestImage.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

Comment: Which client components do you use?

Comment: @Victoria FireDAC

Comment: Not surprising, SQL 2000 is ancient history, and has been officially dropped from support 4 years ago. Microsoft refuses to even release security patches for it. Even SQL 2005 support ended last year. Anyway, does the SQL Server service use a Windows account which has write access to the C:\ root?

Comment: @JerryDodge you are right, the problem is the client still using old accounting system which is unfortunately need SQL 2000 exclusively.
Yes the SQL Server Service is use Windows account.

Comment: Of course it uses a Windows account, my question was does this account have write to the directory where your file is located?

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes

Comment: @JerryDodge ? So do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

### How to insert image into database?

Have an [**IMAGE**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) type field (should be available in SQL Server 2000):

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
   Picture IMAGE
)
```

And insert an image into it:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Picture) VALUES (:ID, :Picture)';
FDQuery1.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := 1;
FDQuery1.ParamByName('Picture').AsStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\Image.jpg', fmOpenRead);
FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

The stream created above will be released after query unpreparing, or after next value assignment.

### How to display image in a TDBImage control?

Drop [**TDBImage**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBImage) control on your form with [**TDataSource**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSource) and [**TFDQuery**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDQuery), for example. Now connect these components and setup source field for the image:

```
DataSource1.DataSet := FDQuery1;
DBImage1.DataSource := DataSource1;
DBImage1.DataField := 'Picture';
```

And query for data, for example:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Picture FROM MyTable WHERE ID = :ID';
FDQuery1.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := 1;
FDQuery1.Open;
```

Comment: thank you, but the insert statment should from sql itself not from Delphi, is it possible?

Comment: You're welcome! I'm a bit lost why is this question tagged Delphi and FireDAC, but well, give [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214485/8041231) a try. You can write a stored procedure based on it.

Answer (score -2):

Inserting image into table using TADOQuery;

```
Create Table new_table(
var1...,
var2...,
.,
.,
.,
image1 as type image ,
)
```

Add the following to your user interface:
Jpeg (Sometimes not added by default)

Add the following objects to your project:

- `TOpenPictureDialog (oppCompanyLogo)`
- `TImage (imgCompanyLogo)`
- `TButton`

Event for the button as follows:

```
if oppCompanyLogo.Execute then
begin
  imgCompanyLogo.Picture.LoadFromFile(oppCompanyLogo.FileName);
end;
```

- Image is now assigned to `TIamge` (imgCompanyLogo) object;
- Add

  ```
  var JPG : TJPEGImage`
  JPG := TJPEGImage.Create;
  JPG.Assign(imgCompanyLogo.Picture);
  ```
- Image is now assigned to Jpeg image JPG,

Now we going to simply add the image to the table using `TADOQuery`:

- Assumption - You already created your connection to the db (to setup this please create new post)

  ```
  with TADOQuery_name do
    begin
       Close;
       Tablename := tablename1;
       Open;
       Insert;
       FieldByName('Var1')...;
       FieldByName('Var2')...;
       .
       .
       .
       FieldByName('Image1').Assign(JPG);
       Post;
       Close;
     End;
  ```

Simplicity...